# Getting trouble with npm run start.android in angular2seed

Tags: android, node.js, typescript, nativescript, angular2-seed

I am using `angular2seed-advanced` [Check here](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular2-seed-advanced). And i follow the steps mantioned in that. while developing app i give `npm start` i got the http://localhost:5555/ and it correctly dispalyed on browser. after that when i give the command that which is for `android`

ie, `npm run start`.

android i got an error Unable to install dependencies. Make sure your `package.json` is valid and all dependencies are correct. Error is: The package `@angular/core@2.1.0-beta.0` does not satisfy its siblings' `peerDependencies` requirements!. while running npm install command i got

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.1.0-beta.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.1.0-beta.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.1.0-beta.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.1.0-beta.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.1.0-beta.0
```

what should i do? anyone  please provide solution for this. here i attached my `package.json` file

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^0.6.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/tsc-wrapped": "^0.3.0",
"@types/async": "^2.0.31",
"@types/browser-sync": "^0.0.32",
"@types/connect-livereload": "^0.5.29",
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.32",
"@types/express": "^4.0.32",
"@types/gulp": "^3.8.31",
"@types/gulp-load-plugins": "^0.0.27",
"@types/gulp-protractor": "^1.0.28",
"@types/gulp-sass": "^0.0.28",
"@types/gulp-shell": "^0.0.28",
"@types/gulp-util": "^3.0.28",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.2.33",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.36",
"@types/node": "^6.0.38",
"@types/protractor": "^1.5.18",
"@types/rimraf": "^0.0.27",
"@types/run-sequence": "^0.0.27",
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.*",
"@types/systemjs": "^0.19.30",
"@types/yargs": "^0.0.30",
"@types/zone.js": "^0.0.26",
"async": "^2.0.1",
"autoprefixer": "^6.3.7",
"browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
"codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.0",
"colorguard": "^1.2.0",
"compression": "^1.6.2",
"connect": "^3.4.1",
"connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
"connect-livereload": "^0.5.4",
"cssnano": "^3.7.3",
"deep-extend": "^0.4.1",
"doiuse": "^2.4.1",
"electron-connect": "^0.4.2",
"electron-debug": "^1.0.0",
"electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.1",
"event-stream": "^3.3.3",
"express": "~4.14.0",
"express-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
"extend": "^3.0.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-atom-electron": "^1.6.1",
"gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
"gulp-clean-css": "^2.0.11",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
"gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
"gulp-inject": "^4.1.0",
"gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^3.0.1",
"gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.4",
"gulp-newer": "^1.2.0",
"gulp-plumber": "~1.1.0",
"gulp-postcss": "^6.1.1",
"gulp-progeny": "^0.3.1",
"gulp-protractor": "^2.4.0",
"gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
"gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
"gulp-sass-lint": "^1.2.0",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "2.0.0-alpha",
"gulp-symdest": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-template": "^4.0.0",
"gulp-tslint": "^6.0.1",
"gulp-typedoc": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-typescript": "^3.0.1",
"gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
"gulp-watch": "^4.3.8",
"is-ci": "^1.0.9",
"isstream": "^0.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.5.0",
"karma": "~0.13.22",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage": "^1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.0.2",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.4",
"merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
"open": "0.0.5",
"postcss-reporter": "^1.4.1",
"protractor": "^3.3.0",
"remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
"rimraf": "^2.5.3",
"run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
"semver": "^5.3.0",
"serve-static": "^1.11.1",
"slash": "~1.0.0",
"stylelint": "^7.0.2",
"stylelint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
"systemjs-builder": "0.15.31",
"tildify": "^1.2.0",
"traceur": "^0.0.111",
"ts-node": "^1.0.0",
"tslint": "^3.13.0",
"tslint-stylish": "2.1.0-beta",
"typedoc": "^0.4.5",
"typescript": "2.0.2",
"walk": "^2.3.9",
"yargs": "^4.8.0"
 },
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/core": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/forms": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/http": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/router": "^3.1.0-beta.0",
"@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
"angulartics2": "^1.1.5",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"es-module-loader": "^1.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.15.0",
"ng2-translate": "^2.4.4",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.38",
"zone.js": "0.6.23"
}
}
```

nativescript/package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/core": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/forms": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/http": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^2.1.0-beta.0",
"@angular/router": "^3.1.0-beta.0",
"@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
"angulartics2": "^1.1.6",
"es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"lodash": "^4.15.0",
"nativescript-angular": "next",
"nativescript-ng2-translate": "^1.2.0",
"nativescript-theme-core": "0.0.10",
"ng2-translate": "^2.4.4",
"parse5": "1.4.2",
"punycode": "1.3.2",
"querystring": "0.2.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"tns-core-modules": "^2.3.0",
"url": "0.10.3"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"zone.js": "^0.6.21",
"babel-traverse": "6.12.0",
"babel-types": "6.11.1",
"babylon": "6.8.4",
"filewalker": "0.1.2",
"lazy": "1.0.11",
"nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
"shelljs": "^0.7.0",
"typescript": "^1.8.10"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in this version of angular-seed. But in previous versions I had same problems.

Fix was install `zone.js` and `rxjs` first.

1. removing `node_modules` from root and nativescript folder
2. install `zone.js` and `rxjs`
3. tns install

something like this. Maybe installing order was off.

It maybe other dependency than zone.js and rxjs.

you can try `npm -i @angular/common@2.1.0-beta.0` to see which dependencies are unmet

Hope this helps

---

UPDATE 1
After I tried `cd nativescript && npm i` command gave me following error.

```
npm WARN ng2-translate@2.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-translate@2.5.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@~2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngrx/store@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngrx/effects@2.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

this means version 2.5.0 of plugin ng2-translate requires version ~2.0.0 of @angular/core. But  version ~2.0.0 of @angular/core is not installed.

So downgrading few beta version in `nativescript/package.json` file fixed the problem run on my machine.

```
"@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^3.0.0",
```

I advice to ask developers directly on github or slack channel, or use stable release of that repo. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. i follow your instructions. that is i install "zone.js": "^0.6.21" and "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12". after that applied tns install --path nativescript. the i got an error The package @angular/core@2.1.0-beta.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!.

Comment: also tried  npm install @angular/common@2.1.0-beta.0
den the result is:                                                                                        +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.1.0-beta.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.1.0-beta.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.1.0-beta.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.1.0-beta.0
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.1.0-beta.0

Comment: All i can tell is 

`cd nativescript`
`rm -rf node_modules && npm i`

displays which plugin has unmet dependency

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: when i gave this command rm -rf node_modules && npm i i got UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.1.0-rc.0 and 
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.1.0-rc.0